# Microsoft Azure Email: Upgrade to Standard SKU public IP addresses in Azure by 30 September 2025—Basic SKU will be retired

Tags: azure, ip-address

Microsoft emailed out notice to upgrade to standard public IP. I have a hard time understanding Microsoft usually, So hopefully someone can explain this to me in a better way. I am not sure how to handle this change exactly. Here are a few questions....

1. The email states Basic SKU public IP will be retired in 2025. When I click their link for pricing basic is on the price list. So if basic is being retired why wouldn't it just default to standard?
2. If it does need to be changed to keep my current static IP addresses will I have to reconfigure all of my firewall rules and network configs within Azure?
3. Does this mean I will have to disassociate the IP's on each server to be able to upgrade or even view my options? Will the IP's even still be mine or will I get new ones?
4. Downtime would be a big issue. How much Downtime am I looking at and what are somethings I can do to reduce it?

I have tried to see my options by going to the Public IP address resource. When I click upgrade it says my IP is currently associated and can not upgrade at this time. I have alot of older equipment that connects to my servers and it would require onsite/remote visits to each site to manually change the IP address's.

Answer (score 0):

If you will upgrade a basic IP which is "static" it will NOT change. A dynamic IP would change, as it would need to be disassociated from the VM for the upgrade. ([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/virtual-network-public-ip-address#:~:text=Dynamic%20addresses%20can%20change%20if,from%20within%20the%20guest%20OS.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/virtual-network-public-ip-address#:%7E:text=Dynamic%20addresses%20can%20change%20if,from%20within%20the%20guest%20OS.)) Assuming you are only using IPv4 addresses. v6 with basic are always dynamic, so those would change with the upgrade.

Do you have already reviewed the documentation regarding the upgrade steps?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/public-ip-basic-upgrade-guidance#steps-to-complete-the-upgrade

Depending on your scenarios, the page gives you also some automation scripts to do this.

I would recommend you, to create a migration plan and test this in a separated environment to understand fully the impact for your business.

Comment: Yes I have read the documentation but I struggle understanding some of it. I mainly just want to know best practices for this change for large scale production servers and if there are any tips from someone who has already done this ( Downtime, Effects to Firewalls/configurations etc.).